# How to only allow one row at a time to be selected in a JTable?

Tags: java, java-8, jtable, row

I was wondering what the best way is to make it so that only one row at a time can be selected in a JTable? Is there a method to set this which I have missed or do I need to override it is some way?

I am using Oracle JDK 8.

Comment: did u try : setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION) ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

```
table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
```